Calculate percentage with criteria ignore blank and if no value then null or blank
I have a table with 3 columns, I want to calculate percentage ('Done' Divide Count Column Status without Blank) and if no value to divide result will become null/blank.
From this table



Group
Region
Status




A
1



A
2
Done


A
3
Done


A
1
Done


A
2



A
3
Cancel


A
1
Reschedule


B
1
Cancel


B
1
Reschedule


B
2



B
2
Not Yet


B
3
Reschedule


C
1
Done


C
2



C
3
Reschedule


C
1




into this table



Group
Region
Status Done %




A
1
100%


A
2
100%


A
3
50%


B
1
0%


B
2
0%


B
3
0%


C
1
100%


C
2



C
3
0%



Any ideas of a SELECT SQL query that will allow me to do this?

Do a GROUP BY. Use CASE expression(s) to do conditional aggregation.

To get a null result you need a null divisor: Use sum(case when Status = 'Done' then 1 end) * 100.0 / sum(case when Status is not null /* or <> '' ? */ then 1 end) 

ORACLE (SQL should work with other DBs too)
You need Case expressions to count rows where STATUS is not null and to count rows where STATUS = 'Done' to get the percentages (Case expressions within Count() function).
Additionaly, you need to check if the divisor is nulll (or 0) to avoid error with zero division (Outer Case expression).
Btw. There is a misscalculation (or I missed something) in your expected result for GRP = 'A' and REGION = 1 - that should be 50%. Below is the code:
WITH    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (GRP, REGION, STATUS) AS
        ( Select 'A', 1, Null From Dual Union All   
          Select 'A', 2, 'Done' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'A', 3, 'Done' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'A', 1, 'Done' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'A', 2, Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 'A', 3, 'Cancel' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'A', 1, 'Reschedule' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'B', 1, 'Cancel' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'B', 1, 'Reschedule' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'B', 2, Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 'B', 2, 'Not Yet' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'B', 3, 'Reschedule' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'C', 1, 'Done' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'C', 2, Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 'C', 3, 'Reschedule' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'C', 1, Null From Dual 
        )

--    S Q L : 
Select    GRP, REGION,
          Case  When Nvl(Count(Case When STATUS Is Not Null Then 1 End), 0) > 0
                Then Count(Case When STATUS = 'Done' Then 1 End) * 100 / Count(Case When STATUS Is Not Null Then 1 End) 
          End "DONE_PCT"
From      tbl
Group By  GRP, REGION
Order By  GRP, REGION

/*    R e s u l t : 
GRP     REGION   DONE_PCT
--- ---------- ----------
A            1         50
A            2        100
A            3         50
B            1          0
B            2          0
B            3          0
C            1        100
C            2           
C            3          0     */

